# $G \supset J$, when would its universal cover $\widetilde{G}$ also shows $\widetilde{G} \supset J$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Suppose the Lie group $G$ contains the Lie group $J$ as a subgroup, so
$$
G \supset J.
$$

If $G$ has a nontrivial first homotopy group $\pi_1(G) \neq 0$.

If $G$ has a universal cover $\widetilde{G}$ so $\pi_1(\widetilde{G}) = 0$.

> Question: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions to derive that
> $$
> \widetilde{G} \supset J \quad (?)
> $$
> is also true?

Comment: What does $\widetilde{G}\supset J$ even mean? $G$ and $\widetilde{G}$ are different sets.

Comment: You can take $G=SO(3)$ and $\widetilde{G}=SU(2)$ for example, we are thinking about the lifting. We are not thinking about taking the same set of $J$. Just some way to embed $J$.

Comment: Sufficient condition may be $\pi_1(J)=0$, due to the property $\pi_1(\widetilde{G})$.

Comment: Would it be correct to interpret your question as asking if the inclusion map $\iota:J\to G$ has a lift $\widetilde{\iota}:J\to\widetilde{G}$ (in the category of Lie groups)?

Comment: yes lifting inclusion

Answer (score 1):

First, assume that $J$ and $G$ are connected. In this case, a lift exists iff $\pi_1(\iota)=0$. This is a sufficient condition due to the homotopy lifting property of covering spaces: $\iota$ has a unique continuous lift $\widetilde{\iota}$ satisfying $\widetilde{\iota}(e)=\widetilde{e}$, and this lift is always a group homomorphism. It is necessary due to fundamental groups: such a $\widetilde{\iota}$ must satisfy $\pi_1(c)\circ\pi_1(\widetilde{\iota})=\pi_1(\iota)$, and sice $\pi_1(\widetilde{G})=0$, this is only possible if $\pi_1(\iota)=0$.

For the general case, let $c:\widetilde{G}\to G$ be the universal covering map, and note that $\widetilde{J}:=c^{-1}(J)$ is a Lie subgroup of $\widetilde{G}$, and the restriction of the universal covering $\hat{c}:\widetilde{J}\to J$ is a covering homomorphism. A necessary condition is that $\iota$ has a lift when restricted to identity compinents; this is the case iff $\pi_1(\iota)=0$ by the argument from the connected case. Another neccesary condition is that $\pi_0(\hat{c})$ has a right inverse. I claim that, when combined, these two conditions are also sufficient. The basic argument is that $\hat{c}$ restricts to a diffeomorphism on each connected component of $\widetilde{J}$, so given a map $\psi:\pi_0(J)\to\pi_0(\widetilde{J})$ with $\pi_0(\hat{c})\circ\psi=\operatorname{id}_{\pi_0(J)}$, we can invert these diffeomorphisms to obtain a lift $\widetilde{\iota}:J\to\widetilde{J}$ with $\pi_0(\widetilde{\iota})=\psi$.

Comment: many thanks +1 - I will read in detail